# Why is such strange code generated?

Tags: assembly, x86, g++

Consider a piece of C++ code:

```
int main()
{
    volatile int a=0;
    if(!a)
        ++a;
}
```

I compile it on amd64 system with 
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04) with command `g++ test.cpp -S -o test.S -masm=intel` and get the following code:

```
...
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [ebp-4]
    test    eax, eax
    sete    al
    test    al, al
    je  .L2
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [ebp-4] ; don't use result of sete
    add eax, 1
    mov DWORD PTR [ebp-4], eax
.L2:
    mov eax, 0 ; also drop result of sete
...
```

This code really surprises me. At first I thought it has something to do with 64-bit mode. But when I tried to compile with `-m32`, this bit remained the same.

Why does it check `eax` for being zero and then recheck the result once more after setting `al` to `ZF`? Why doesn't it just do `test eax,eax\n jne .L2`?

Comment: Turn on optimizations (-O3 on the command line) and the useless instructions will disappear.

Comment: @NilsPipenbrinck I'm aware of optimizations. The question is about why it is so, not how to fix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it has to do with how `bool` is handled differently in C and C++.  In your code, the `if(!a)` first converts `a` to a `bool` (that's what the `test eax, eax; sete al` does), and *then* tests that boolean (in `al`) for true/false.

If you rename as `.c` and compile the same code with `gcc`, it generates the expected code

```
    mov DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
    test    eax, eax
    jne .L3
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
    add eax, 1
    mov DWORD PTR [rbp-4], eax
.L3:
```

In C, it seems that boolean tests of integral variables happens without the intermediate conversion to `bool`. Note that `al` is never involved, so this implies that the value is never "converted" to a one-byte `bool` before testing it for non-zero.

Comment: Perhaps one of the C / C++ language gurus can point out the exact wording from the spec here - I'm having difficulty finding it.